# How is a digital certificate generated?

Tags: openssl, certificates

I understand that the role of a Certificate Authority is to SIGN (not encrypt) a certificate. The signed certificate will theoretically contain:

1. Plain text of data, including the server's public key
2. Signature of hashed version of plain text of data in (1) so that a user can verify (using CA public key) that the certificate has not been tampered with.

Knowing these two key points, I tried to play around with an example cert

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried decoding using Base64 decoder, and the result is gibberish. I tried googling for answers but I'm not getting anywhere.

1. What encoding scheme is this and does this offer extra layer of security?
2. Shouldn't the main ideas (point 1 and 2) be secure enough?
3. Is there a way I can break this blob down to visually show that data part and the signature part?

Comment: If you have openssl on your system then `openssl x509 -in name-of-cert-file -noout -text` will give you a human readble version of the certificate

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Plain text of data, including server's public key

Yes, and many other public information, including something identifying the holder of the public key (perhaps in the Common Name field).

> 2. Signature of hashed version of plain text

Yes, except that the correct semantic is: Signature of the plain text. Building and verifying the signature includes hashing plain text.

> What encoding scheme is this?

See [RFC 7468 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-5) and what it references, including [RFC 1421 section 4.3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.3.2.4) for the translation of binary to text (which in a nutshell is per [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

> Does this offer extra layer of security?

From a cryptographic standpoint, no. That's merely a [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201510/903600) for rationale.

> Shouldn't the main ideas (point 1 and 2) be secure enough?

Yes, they are.

> Is there a way I can break this blob down to visually show that data part and the signature part?

When there's any non-confidential piece of standard text-encoded stuff to decode, it can be thrown at the marvelous https://lapo.it/asn1js/ (with or without the delimiters) and the results are usually pretty good. When in doubt about the confidentiality, use a local copy in an isolated VM.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the benefits of using x509 vs base 64 of json string for example

Comment: @Zanko: X.509 does not oppose to Base64, which happens to be the binary-to-text encoding used (I added references). X.509 (and what it references) defines the format of the binary blob. Won't comment _"base 64 of json string"_, for that's squarely off-topic (even more than the details of the certificate format).